# Can connect via smbclient but not mount CIFS

Tags: linux, samba, mac, cifs

I have a weird problem: I can connect to a samba server (on a Mac) from a Linux machine using `smbclient` but do not manage to mount the samba share using `CIFS`

The `smbclient` command which works is:

```
smbclient -U MYUSERNAME -W X.YYY.ZZ -m SMB2 -d 3 //SERVER/LEEF
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
added interface ens3 ip=xx.xx.xx.xx bcast=yy.yy.yy.yy netmask=255.255.0.0
added interface docker0 ip=zz.zz.zz.zz bcast=pp.pp.pp.pp netmask=255.255.240.0
Client started (version 4.7.6-Ubuntu).
tdb(/var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name xxxxxxxxx<0x20>
Connecting to rr.rr.rr.rr at port 445
got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
Enter X.YYY.ZZ\ MYUSERNAME's password:
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.
smb: \>
```

I tried the following mount command

```
sudo mount -t cifs  //SERVER/LEEF /mnt/LEEF_IEU/ -o username=MYUSERNAME,domain=X.YYY.ZZ,vers=2.0
```

but I get an

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

with all other `vers=` I get an

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I am at a loss here and have the feeling, I am missing the obvious. Any suggestions what is going on here and how I can mount the samba share (not necessarily cifs)?

Thanks.